# Laravel : How to hide user's own profile from friend list?

Tags: laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

There are three tables: **users, profiles, friend_request**

profiles table's column : **profile_id, id (foreign key with users) , first_name,last_name**

friend_request's table column : **request_id, sender_id,to_user_id, request_status**

logic : if **profile_id** exist in either **sender_id** column or **to_user_id** of **friend_request** table with **request_status** 2 then they are friends.

example : sender_id    to_user_id   request_status

```
           5          6            2

$request_accept = DB::table('friend_request')->select('profiles.profile_id','profiles.first_name',
'friend_request.request_id')->leftjoin('profiles', function($join)
 {
   $join->on('friend_request.sender_id' , '=','profiles.profile_id');
   $join->orOn('friend_request.to_user_id' , '=','profiles.profile_id');
  }
 )->where('to_user_id',$my_profile_id)->orwhere('sender_id',$my_profile_id)->where('interest_status','2')->whereNotIn('profiles.profile_id', function($q) use ($my_profile_id)
  {
   $q->select('profile_id')->from('profiles')->where('profile_id',$my_profile_id);
   })->groupby('profiles.profile_id')->get();
```

wherenotin i snot working.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking...

Probably better to make these all models, with relationships, then you could do a much simpler query, for example like this.

Assume your `friend_request` table now has a `FriendRequest` model with a `user` relationship.  The query below uses a `$userId`, assume this is the ID for the user whom you wish to get all the friend requests.

```
FriendRequest::where('to_user_id', $my_profile_id)->get();
```

If everything is set up correctly, the user will not be returned as they cannot send themselves a friend request.

Comment: i am using query builder not eloquent.

Comment: Good luck then.